# Here document is cutting off commands

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to connect to my server via SSH and issue some commands to it. For some reason it seems like the commands are getting cut "off".

Here is the code that does the putty connection as well as issuing the SSH commands:

```
./plink.exe ${USER}@${HOSTNAME} -pw ${PASS}<<SSH
cd /some/foo/bar
deploy_artifact.sh --instance development1 some_artifact.ear
APP_development1.sh restart
exit
SSH
```

For me it works, but on the machine of my colleague the issued SSH commands are getting cut off and thus are not interpreted correctly. For example `deploy_artifact.sh` is getting turned into `ploy_artifact.sh` (See the following the screenshot).

[image]

How can i prevent this? And what is causing this?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Make sure you script isn't using DOS line endings.

Comment: There's something else going on as well; `APP_development1.sh` doesn't appear in the code you posted above.

Comment: @chepner Sorry, i made a mistake there. I updated the code.

Comment: @chepner According to notepad++ the endings are already in UNIX format (LF)

Comment: Does the same problem occur when the script is read from a file with the use of the `-m commands.sh` option? Also, you can try updating the ssh server on the target machine. Either the ssh server is dropping the first characters or the ssh client does not send them.

Comment: @Dzienny Seems to work when i read it from the file via `-m` thanks! But wat is the exact underlying issue here? It seems weird to me that this happens at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the problem is with the `plink` and how it is used. The given example sends commands as a standard input, however I did not find in the `plink` manual any mention that it reads commands from the STDIN. It is better to avoid undocumented features, since they may not work correctly or the author may remove them without any notice. Instead, if you want to pass commands inline you should provide them as an argument, ie you either have to use a quoted text, or you can wrap heredoc in the [`"$(cat *heredoc* )"` code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664229/here-document-as-an-argument-to-bash-function), eg:

```
./plink.exe ${USER}@${HOSTNAME} -pw ${PASS} "$(cat <<SSH
cd /some/foo/bar
deploy_artifact.sh --instance development1 some_artifact.ear
APP_development1.sh restart
exit
SSH
)"
```

Or, you can keep the commands in a file and run the `plink` with the `-m commands_file` option.